# adding and removing panels when rectangles intersect

Tags: java

I'm making a game and when the user is in one of the game map panels he should enter the game once the character rectangle intersects with the game button rectangle on the map. The user navigates the character using the arrow keys.

I have the following code in the keyPressed method for one of the map panels (its the same for the rest) and the button (game1) reacts to the intersection as it should but the add and remove statements aren't adding or removing the respective panels:

```
Rectangle rb1 = character.getBounds();
Rectangle rb2 = game1.getBounds();

if (rb1.intersects(rb2)){
    game1.setText("Int");
    game1.setBackground(Color.red);
    remove(sp);
    add(g1, "Center");
    validate();
    repaint();
}
```

Initially I thought putting that block in the keyPressed method was what's causing the issue but when i moved it, the game1 button stopped reacting entirely. Any help is welcomed and appreciated :)

Here is the code in that panel:

```
public class SportsPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel implements KeyListener {

    JButton homeButton2;
    JButton game1;
    JButton game2;
    JButton game3;
    JButton game4;
    JButton game5;
    SportsPanel sp;
    JLabel character;
    CharacterMenu cm;
    ControlPanel cp;
    game1 g1;
    game2 g2;
    game3 g3;
    game4 g4;
    game5 g5;
    JTextField scoreField;
    int c =1;
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;

public SportsPanel() {
    cm = new CharacterMenu();
    g1 = new game1();
    g2 = new game2();
    g3 = new game3();
    g4 = new game4();
    g5 = new game5();
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.white);

    homeButton2 = new JButton("Back to Main Menu");
    add(homeButton2);
    homeButton2.setBounds(10, 629, 150, 40);

    character = new JLabel("");
    character.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
    add(character);

    game1 = new JButton("Game 1");
    add(game1);
    game1.setBounds(200,200, 100, 20);

    game2 = new JButton("Game 2");
    add(game2);
    game2.setBounds(340, 20, 100, 20);

    game3 = new JButton("Game 3");
    add(game3);
    game3.setBounds(120,458, 100, 20);

    game4 = new JButton("Game 4");
    add(game4);
    game4.setBounds(458,269, 100, 20);

    game5 = new JButton("Game 5");
    add(game5);
    game5.setBounds(2, 500, 100, 20);

    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);

    scoreField = new JTextField("  Time elapsed: ");
    scoreField.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 50);
    add(scoreField);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    requestFocusInWindow();

    Image myImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/sports.png");
    g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, 925, 699, this);
    if(c == 1){
        ImageIcon lion1 = new ImageIcon("images/lion.png");
        ImageIcon newSize = new ImageIcon(((lion1).getImage()).getScaledInstance(100, 100, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        character.setText("");
        character.setIcon(newSize);
    }
    if(c == 2){
        ImageIcon franklin1 = new ImageIcon("images/franklin.png");
        ImageIcon newSize = new ImageIcon(((franklin1).getImage()).getScaledInstance(100, 100, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        character.setText("");
        character.setIcon(newSize);
    }
    if(c == 3){
        ImageIcon saquon1 = new ImageIcon("images/saquon.png");
        ImageIcon newSize = new ImageIcon(((saquon1).getImage()).getScaledInstance(100, 100, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        character.setText("");
        character.setIcon(newSize);
    }


}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("Key pressed");
    int kk = evt.getKeyCode();
    if (kk == evt.VK_LEFT)
    {
        x = x - 5;;
    }
    if (kk == evt.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        x = x + 5;
    }
    if (kk == evt.VK_UP)
    {
        y = y - 5;
    }
    if (kk == evt.VK_DOWN)
    {
        y = y + 5;
    }
    character.setBounds(new Rectangle(x, y, 100, 100));

    Rectangle rb1 = character.getBounds();
    Rectangle rb2 = game1.getBounds();

    if (rb1.intersects(rb2)){
        game1.setText("Int");
        game1.setBackground(Color.red);
        remove(sp);
        add(g1, "Center");
        validate();
        repaint();
    }

    }

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
    }
```

}

Comment: Edit your question to include the full source code you have. Also try setting a breakpoint inside the if statement. Does your debugger stop there when the rectangle should intersect?

Comment: @Progman the if statement is executed because the first two lines are applied; the game1 button text changes to "Int"... but for some reason the adding and removing doesn't go through

Comment: The source code is not complete, there are a lot of classes missing. There isn't even the `main()` method where your program starts. Keep in mind that you should post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can only guess whats going on when we don't see the other classes which deal with this class. As an example, where do you set the value for the `sp` field?